# Vaadin export to pdf

Tags: pdf, export, vaadin

I have to fix incorect page layout for report exported to pdf.  In some browsers you could see framing around rows in some you don´t. I tried to check css style, but it does´t seem it´s configured there. Could anyone suggest where to look for reason why framing doesn´t work?
I actually discovered that problem is in page break settings. I have tried to use

```
 @media print{
               #tableWrapper{page-break-inside: avoid;}
              }
           .innerTable{

                   margin-bottom: 15;
                 page-break-inside: avoid;
             }
```

But this won´t solve the problem.But it is as close i can get to solution. Html is generated by Vaadin. So there is not way (at least that i know of how to adjust tables in html...)

```
<table class="mainTable">
<tr><td/><td/>...<tr/>
<table class="innerTable">
<th><th/>
<tr><td/><td/><tr/>
</table>
</table>
</table>
```

how to specify i want  to avoid this break inside innerTable ?

Comment: Please add the code you are using to show the problem. As of now, no one will be able to answer that question from the description (unless we come over to your computer and see for yourself).

Comment: Is the PDF generated on server side or on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it at last! All i had to do was to add margins for top and bottom and then specify this:

```
      @media print {
         .mainTable {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
                    }
       .innerTable, .mainTable tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
                    }
```

Turns out class naming int HTML for CSS wasn´t exactly fortunate solution. But now it works.